# Reading from file and using integer as indices in Array

Tags: java, arrays, hash, hashtable, key-value

I have a use case where I need to read pair of integers from a file, where the first integer should act as an index of an array, and the second one as value for that index.

For example if file contains

```
12 10
```

10 should be the value on index 12. How can I do that in Java?

Comment: What are you stuck on? Reading the integer pairs? Assigning a value in an array at a specific index? You might want to post some code showing your attempts, unless you want people commenting http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Please show your code and explain where you're struggling.

Answer (score 0):

To store in an array is not a good idea as you don’t know what would be the largest index in a given file and you would end up with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Use `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` to store the data from the file.

First integer will be the key & second integer will be the value of that key.

I would suggest you read about Maps in java first and implement it yourself. :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way.